# Only wallpaper and cursor showing

Tags: unity, 12.10

I searched through a lot of forums and googled in general, but I just can't find the answer. So I will ask here, and am a hopeful of a solution from you folks.

New to Linux and all that, but pretty familiar with computers.

Installed 12.10 on an old Dell Dimension 3000 Desktop. Installation was slow but  completed without problems.

After reading around a bit, I am nearly positive that this must have something to do with the video drivers, but again, I have not seen anyone with exactly similar nature to my situation that has a valid solution.

After logging in, I am left with the wallpaper and a functioning cursor- nothing more. I am able to open a terminal with the hotkey <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>, and able to exit the GUI straight to command interface with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>.

Even after multiple updates, downloads, installs and even reinstallation, I am stuck. Anyone able to shed some light? Please ask for any necessary specifications.

Comment: Is Dell Dimension 3000 a computer from 2004? What grapgics does it have? Generally, 12.10 is not going to work well on very old hardware. Try installing [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) instead.

Comment: Are you sure the video drivers are involved? Please, try this solution: http://askubuntu.com/a/461502/169738

Answer (score 0):

I was able to `unity --reset` my configuration back-to-life. But you may also want to try [re-installing](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2039619) gnome-session (or ubuntu-desktop.)

Also.. What happens if you drop to a shell (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>), install `xinit`, enter `exec gnome-session --session=ubuntu` into your `.xinitrc` and run `startx`?

Comment: If I read correctly, I don't think that unity --reset is possible on 12.10. I most definitely could be wrong, though.