# Ubuntu 14.04 displays only background with no Launcher after log in

Tags: launcher, 14.04

Upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 64bit and now after logging in all I get is my background screen. Almost seems like a driver issue with my graphics card. I can't even launch a terminal. I can however hold ctrl/alt F1 and access terminal that way. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have done unity desktop reinstall and reset, updated to latest kernel, purged nvidia drivers, and readjusted resolution in grub to match my monitor. And sudo service lightdm restart. All with no success.

Comment: Okay so after hours of looking this tread   ( http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration) seems to have done the trick for me. the only thing you have to do after running the commands listed in the thread is open another terminal and issue the command sudo reboot, log in and wait a few seconds. At first it looks like it didn't work but then it does.

Comment: Finally find a way to get back my launcher.... I tried evverything I could online (including switch environment desktop from gnome to kubuntu) before finding this one. http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration I don't know if the problem was fully from gnome or not but I don't want to take the risk. I hope it will help others.

Comment: My similar issues was solved by answer http://askubuntu.com/a/481620/28943 on question http://askubuntu.com/questions/449845/problems-after-upgrading-to-14-04-only-background-and-pointer-after-login

Answer (score 1):

I'm an Ubuntu newbie moving over from Windows XP!

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 13 to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32-bit, laptop with dual monitors.

While doing the upgrade my system got stuck on the black Ubuntu logo loading screen for an hour or two. I eventually had to do a hard shutdown.

Restarting the computer, I as able to get to the Ubuntu OS, I could see my desktop background and was able to use my wireless mouse to move the cursor between the two screens. No launcher, no GUI. Again, I was only able to do a hard shutdown

I was able to login using recovery mode and could use my laptop as usual (dual monitors, internet etc) but extremely slow.

**The next day, by accident, I started up the laptop forgetting to plug the power board into the power supply. It started up and loaded Ubuntu 14.04 perfectly!!**

**I plugged it in, my 2nd monitor turned on, and was mirroring my laptop. I opened up System Settings, and instantly my 2nd monitor remembered my previous settings.**

It works great now, but starting up with the 2nd monitor turned off is just a work-around for now.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me. Now, if you use ubuntu 11.10 or before, it is very easy to change but if you have ubuntu 12.04 or later, finding out how to do this is a nightmare. All you have to do is get the launcher image. to do so, enter

```
cd && wget -O Ubuntu.po http://drive.noobslab.com/data/Mac-14.04/change-name-on-panel/ubuntu.po
```

Now you have to copy the image to `/usr/share/unity/5`. enter

```
sudo nautilus
```

and copy the `launcher_bfb.png` to `usr/share/unity/5`

logout login and done! :D

and Also if you find a launcher image for ubuntu 12.04 then please post the link. Thank you and your welcome ;)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, also with mint17 (a little different). After install both systems, first on mint changing the viedeodriver to nividia 3.04 mint was fine.
Second starting vom boot menue ubuntu 14.041. boot grub rescuce, then resume. ubuntu came up correct after login. (IF you make ashutdown the problem persist.) Repeat it twice.
The next trial like above I made the change of the grafikdriver like it did it on mint and all updates. Now ubuntu works nomally. So my conclusion is, that the grafikdriver on the orginal ubuntu-system ist the problem. Many of my friends have this problem to.

Comment: Please link the driver you used. Also; welcome to the community.