# Unity not loading, how can I troubleshoot?

Tags: 14.04, unity, login, fglrx

All of a sudden, when I log in to Ubuntu 14.04, I have no top menu bar, no launcher, no dash, only my desktop. Shortcuts like `alt-F2` don't work either. Logging in as guest <s>works</s> worked fine.

At first I tried the ubuntu-tweak-tool tips laid out **[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453482/update-to-14-04-unity-is-not-loading-after-i-login-to-the-admin-profile-after)**, and ran `unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity`. The only effect, though was that Unity stopped working for all accounts! I also tried the compizconfig-settings-manager mentioned in [many](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) [threads](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453482/update-to-14-04-unity-is-not-loading-after-i-login-to-the-admin-profile-after), with no effect.

I also tried reinstalling `ubuntu-deskop` and `unity`.

Don't know if it's relevant, but if I log in as guest, do ctrl-alt-F1 to open a terminal, log in as my user, run `startx' to open another gui session, and then try starting Unity from the terminal, it says “Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE”.

Also, `~/.xsession-errors` has a lot of error like this:

```
 AccountsService-WARNING **: SetInputSources call failed: GDBus.Error: org.freedesktop.Accounts,Error.PermissionDenied: Not Authorized
```

What else can I do to troubleshoot?

The following workaround will give most of Unity (not the top menu bar) back around 50 % of the times, *but only for the current session*: Switch to terminal, and then

```
export DISPLAY=:0
unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
unity
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Comment: Well, the issue is the same, but I have tried every single solution mentioned in any of the answers, that is still relevant for 14.04. Don't know if that makes it ok to start a new, 14.04 question?

Comment: Yes, it's OK to start a new question in case there is anything that has changed in Ubuntu 14.04 that is why all the answers to the linked question did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the solution was to purge and reinstall `fglrx*`, where obviously some setting had gone wrong:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

Comment: Note: This is only applicable to AMD Radeon.