# Unity stopped working. Blank desktop

Tags: unity, 14.04, unity-dash

I was having problems installing MongoDB with NPM and I found someone saying that the problem is related to the fact that I had Python 2 and 3 installed. So I removed Python 3 and after this many Ubuntu apps disappeared.

After rebooting, Unity stopped working and I can't open terminal, view my apps, etc.

I've reinstalled unity and also tried to install gnome, but it still doesn't work.

What do I have to do?

Comment: i recommend you to switch to GNOME environment from unity as the same problem was faced by me to  and i got away from it by downloading gnome version of 14.04 you can download it from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/GetUbuntuGNOME

Comment: I've seen several options to solve the problem.

In my case the Unity plugin being disabled was the problem:
    http://askubuntu.com/questions/453482/update-to-14-04-unity-is-not-loading-after-i-login-to-the-admin-profile-after/

I solved it in this way:
    http://askubuntu.com/questions/453482/update-to-14-04-unity-is-not-loading-after-i-login-to-the-admin-profile-after/453701#comment646541_453701

Comment: I already have compizconfig manager and tried to run ccsm but it throwing an error (I'll check the error message when I get home to add to the question).

Comment: Try this answer to a similar question that happened while running Ubuntu 13.04: http://askubuntu.com/questions/384033/ubuntu-software-center-terminal-and-other-applications-dont-work-after-uninsta/384041#384041

Comment: This happened to me to, what I ended up doing is reinstalling Unity and Gnome from the shell and running an open command for showing the desktop. I had a friend walk me through it and don't remember much, but I hope it helps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)