# Ubuntu Upgrade 13.10 to 14.04 - Why isnt X Using My 3D Hardware Anymore?

Tags: 13.10, nvidia, upgrade, graphics, 14.04

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04, but now I cant login and see my desktop. I get all the way to the login screen and enter my password, but after pressing enter I get left with the 14.04 LTS splash screen. I get the same when trying to login as guest.

I can press CTRL-ALT-F1 and login on the terminal. From the terminal I checked that I'm using the proprietry driver (nvidia 331 (proprietry, tested)).

When I tried to run unity from the terminal I see the error "compiz: open gl not loaded"

Any ideas much appreciated.

UPDATE:
Is this heading the way of save me stuff from the terminal and fresh install 14.04?

FIX:
For people following in my footsteps the fix can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454779/unity-will-not-boot-load-after-upgrade-from-13-10-to-14-04/457369#457369)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unity will not boot/load after upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/454779/unity-will-not-boot-load-after-upgrade-from-13-10-to-14-04)

Answer (score 0):

after login to the terminal , try to `rm ~/.Xauthority`  and then reboot 
I had a similar issue and that was the solution

Comment: Nice try, but this didnt work. I think I had this before and the symptom was a login loop.