# No video signal for nvidia driver

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, gpu-driver

I followed the steps in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/454954/18599) entering these commands as I had a similar problem...

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop 
sudo apt-get install unity 
sudo apt-get purge nvidia* bumblebee* 
sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime 
sudo shutdown -r now
```

...but, after rebooting, I lose video signal during the boot sequence before the log in screen.

How can I get the video signal back? I have Ubuntu 14.04 and nvidia graphics card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime` part of the linked answer installed an incompatible video driver.

I resolved this by:

1. booting into the advanced options from the grub menu,
2. selecting the first recovery mode option,
3. selecting the start networking option,
4. selecting the command prompt as root option

From the command prompt, I entered `apt-get install nvidia-current` 
and installed compatible nvidia drivers.

This solution, or similar for different video cards, may help others with video driver problems.