# graphic ubuntu 13.10 does not start, but terminal is available

Tags: 13.10, graphics

I have Ubuntu 13.10 and I have installed ROS but now I reboot Linux and the screen is in black. If I presh Ctrl+Alt+F2 I get a terminal , and Ctrol+Alt+F7 back to te black screen instead of the Desktop and graphic mode.

Can it be any of these steps of the installation? How can I fix it?

- Configure your Ubuntu repositories or sources.list
- sudo apt-get update
- rosdep update
- echo "source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
- source ~/.bashrc

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Since the first post was deleted here again the whole text:

I also had some problems like that before (insead of the login screen I had a black screen with a cursor).

Are you using fglrx(-updates) as display driver?

> No idea, how can I know if I am using it? –  user2282211

You would know, because you would have selected it in the options.

As I know from my paths through ubuntu there are many ways to get a black screen. In the last time I had a couple of problems:

1. Unity Plugin is disabled. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/76951/326897) for source.

   Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
    `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
    export DISPLAY=:0
    ccsm`
    Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>
   See if Unity Plugin box is ticked
2. Other problems with Ubuntu desktop & Unity. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/454954/326897) for source.

   Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
   `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop 
   sudo apt-get install unity
   sudo reboot`
3. Sometimes it worked for me do uninstall unity and the ubuntu desktop and unity and reinstalling them.