# Unity doesn't load - no Launcher or Dash appears

Tags: 14.04, unity, desktop-environments

I am using 32-bit **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** on my simple Desktop-PC (3GHz Intel P4, 1GB RAM, Intel inbuilt Graphics, and NO extra graphic-card)  <sup>so nothing to worry about graphic like nvidia etc.</sup>

Here is output of `lspci`:

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ/P/PL Memory Controller Hub (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 01)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 3 (rev 01)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 4 (rev 01)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev e1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 01)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 01)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 01)
```

I've installed `xubuntu-desktop` environment, `unity-tweak-tool` which are working fine for 3 month.

Recently I faced problem : [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/q/17381/256099). I've tried the answers, but unable to solve my problem.

Probable reason for this is I've installed `ubuntu-tweak` recently. So, Also I removed it from tty, but unable to solve this problem.

I have Three ways to do anything:

1. Using tty (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>)
2. I've installed `nautilus-open-terminal` so I am able to start `gnome-terminal` by right-click on desktop and "Open Terminal Here".
3. Using Xubuntu Session.

**I have tried following things:**

- Enabling unity-plugin (https://askubuntu.com/a/76951/256099) But not solved.
- `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/` from `gnome-terminal`
- Purged and re-installed `unity`, `compiz` and `ubuntu-desktop`
- Removed cache by `rm -rf ~/.compiz-1 ~/.config/compiz-1`, `sudo rm -fr ~/.compiz`, `sudo rm -fr ~/.cache/*` ,`sudo rm -fr .cache/*`
- Trying to replace/reset unity by following from `gnome-terminal`:

  1. `unity --replace`
  2. `setsid unity`
  3. `ubuntu-tweak-tool --reset-unity`

[**Output-1**](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8477385/), [**Output-2**](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8477390/)

All shows common thing:

```
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: unityshell
WARN  2014-10-02 12:11:25 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:579 Can't register object 'org.gnome.Shell' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
ERROR 2014-10-02 12:11:25 unity.debug.interface DebugDBusInterface.cpp:196 Unable to load entry point in libxpathselect: libxpathselect.so.1.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
WARN  2014-10-02 12:11:25 xim.controller XIMController.cpp:103 IBus natively supported.
ERROR 2014-10-02 12:11:26 nux.gltexture.resource.manager GLTextureResourceManager.cpp:54 Invalid target, impossible to generate a new texture. Impossible to generate a pixbuf: Failed to open file '': No such file or directory
WARN  2014-10-02 12:11:26 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:579 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Launcher' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2014-10-02 12:11:26 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:579 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Dash' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2014-10-02 12:11:26 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:579 Can't register object 'org.gnome.SessionManager.EndSessionDialog' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2014-10-02 12:11:26 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:579 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Session' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2014-10-02 12:11:26 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:579 Can't register object 'org.gnome.ScreenSaver' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I've could try a re-install of whole OS. Or, is there any way to solve this problem?

---

Now what to do? (**Isn't it possible to re-install whole unity desktop environment and use fresh D.E. without such problem?**)

Comment: What happens if you follow the answers to question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/449845/problems-after-upgrading-to-14-04-only-background-and-pointer-after-login Please don't follow the commands blindly. Give us a report what happend with each step. Keep the error- and ok messages. They will be useful for later analysis.

Comment: You should be using a **32-bit** Ubuntu 14.04 install, unless you upgrade to 2GB (or more) of RAM.

Comment: @Pandya As stated, try the things from the question I posted and tell us what the output is. Document it in your question.

Comment: @MadMike I revised.

Comment: Have you added any new ppa's lately?

Comment: Is `libxpathselect1.4` installed? Try `apt-get update && apt-get install `libxpathselect1.4` and report back.

Comment: @Jan I've tried `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libxpathselect1.4` Now?

Comment: Now you should not have `ERROR 2014-10-02 12:11:25 unity.debug.interface DebugDBusInterface.cpp:196 Unable to load entry point in libxpathselect: libxpathselect.so.1.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` any more. Does it work?

Comment: @Pandya, `Segmentation fault` hmm, could you try *Getting a Backtrace* see instructions here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingCompiz

Comment: @Pandya: Does the problem persist after having installed `libxpathselect1`?

Comment: @Jan yes; still unity doesn't load and `Segmentation fault`

Comment: @Pandya, beside Debuging Backtrace, could you post your compiz profile full export

Comment: Do you want Unity or Xfce? I'm seeing them both in your question.  You've only got 1GB of RAM, so Unity would run horribly on your computer. Edit your question saying you want Xfce and not Unity.

Comment: @Sneetsher I think now this question should be closed as off-topic (because of bug-reposrting) or too-board (I am feeling complication /difficulty to examine/debug/resolve problem) right?

Comment: @Pandya, I think so, needs a bug report. leave it till bounty ends, some one may come up a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

Restore default settings

Execute the following commands in terminal, one at time.

```
gconftool --shutdown
sudo killall -r -I gconf
sudo killall -r -I dconf
rm -rf .compiz* .gconf* .config/dconf/ .config/compiz*
```

Be aware that above commands will remove any settings or configuration you've done already. Keyboard layouts (if any) will also be removed. Although above commands will not delete any files, they will restore Unity settings as were, when you installed Ubuntu for the first time.

Reboot your system for changes to take effect.

The same thing happened to me one time, so here's the answer I got that worked.

Comment: I've tried your answer but Can't solve my problem! still giving same error. However this is only about clearing cache or config and it's already answer in related questions!

Comment: try installing gnome. It's not much different from Unity