# Some desktop environments don't work anymore after system changes (reusing `/home` in new install)

Tags: 14.04, unity, compiz, lightdm, desktop-environments

After some reinstallation/configuration/partition resizing work (I really can't say where the point of failure was, but see below for details), I ended up with `unity` not working anymore, a situation essentially similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/17381/76376) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/530902): login works, and then I just get a blank screen.

I've tried several things listed in those questions, like restarting various stuff, purging and reinstalling `compiz`, `unity`, and `ubuntu-desktop`, or deleteting their config files. Also using `compizconfig-settings-manager` and re-enabling the Unity-plugin didn't help (although it *was* disabled, in case that's relevant information).

I then just tried to install alternative desktop environments and display mangers, and that's where things started to get weird: namely, it turned out that `lxde` and `openbox` *do* work under both `lightdm` and `gdm`, while  `unity` and `gnome-shell` don't work on either (after login, just a background image appears and nothing more).

One additional thing that sometimes happened in `lxde` was that an "Internal Error" box showed up, containing (among others) the following information:

> Title: xorg crashed with SIGABRT in __libc_message()
>
> CompizPlugins: No value set for `/apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/active_plugins

(but this only showed up after I already reinstalled and changed many things, so it might be related to problem or not).

Now, I have no idea where the failing is actually happening, but I suspect `compiz`...

---

What I actually was doing before this happended:

- Installing 14.04 on a separate partition (1) from the original installation (2) (also 14.04)
- Normal login, so the default `unity`, `lightdm` and `ubuntu-desktop` did work
- Installing some programs
- Mounting my old `/home` from the old installation, which is on a third partition (3), as `/home` for the new installation (and setting this in the new `fstab`)
- Installing more stuff, and deleting some config directories/files from `~` which I thought are not needed anymore
- At some point here, I have also used `unity-tweak-tool`, but only to increase the number of virtual workspaces
- Resizing partitions (1) and (2)
- Reboot

After the last reboot, said things happended. I don't think the partitioning stuff plays any role, but I mention it for completeness; but maybe my reusing the old `/home` did something weird? On the other hand, I (think I) rebooted at least once with it mounted as `/home` of the new install, without problems.

I also use a dual-monitor setup, but that has never caused any problems.

---

The question is: is there anything else I could do for getting `unity` back and `gnome-shell` work? Or should I just reinstall everything -- in which case, should I *not* just reuse the old `/home`, or would that not be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably some configuration file has gone wrong. Most applications build a default configuration if they don't find thei config directory.

Using a console save your config directories (those starting their name with a ".") into a new folder (e.g. ~/old_configs) - look what happens.

Comment: Wow, as simple as that. For the record: among the automatically newly created config directories were `.config` and `.gconf`, in which I now suspect the source of the problem must have lied (the rest was just `.local`, `.ssh`, `.gnupg` and `.ICEAuthority`).