# Unity doesn't start for only one account

Tags: 14.04, unity

I have several accounts in my Ubuntu 14.04. Only for one of of them, after login, unity doesn't start. I can only see the desktop background and the mouse icon. I tried all the solutions in: [Problems after upgrading to 14.04 (only background and pointer after login)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449845/problems-after-upgrading-to-14-04-only-background-and-pointer-after-login), but they don't work.

Answer (score -1):

After trying some stuff on [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/q/17381/410734), I ended up following [Problems after upgrading to 14.04 (only background and pointer after login)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449845/problems-after-upgrading-to-14-04-only-background-and-pointer-after-login/461502#461502) (warning: it removed the installed programs and settings, but the files were still there):

To fix "username"'s account, if you can get into the login screen or somewhere like that press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> to get to a terminal (tty). Log in with "username" and password.

Now rename the directory `/home/[user_name]/.config/dconf` to `/home/[user_name]/.config/dconf.broken`.

To do this, run

```
cd .config
sudo mv dconf dconf.broken
```

You might need to re-enter your password now. Finally reboot:

```
reboot
```

Comment: Why a restart!? This is totally unnecessary.

Comment: a restart is reassuring because it means that next time you start the computer it will do the same - it only takes a minute

Comment: This is Linux and not Windows. A system restart is not necessary.

Comment: fair enough. you could possibly go ctrl alt F7 or restart unity or whatever. This solution just fixes the symptoms. I have a hunch this is possibly to do with flash. I am just posting what worked for me in the least number of steps