# Upgrade to 14.04 broken

Tags: 14.04, unity, upgrade, ati, display

I recently upgraded from ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 and the screen is blank and unable to login. When CTRL-ALT-F1 to a console and performing the following recommendations [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449845/problems-after-upgrading-to-14-04-only-background-and-pointer-after-login) didnt solve my problem.Additionally running 'xrandr' returns 'n display', which suggests there is a problem with my video card, which is an AMD/ATI Radeon HD 2400 PRO/XT, the screen resolution appears to be defaulting to 1280x1024 when should be 1920x1080.

The computer is a Dell Optiplex 755. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try `sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx` and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Yep resolution problem fixed, now able to login. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I ran the following command after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and logging in:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx
sudo reboot
```