# Missing launcher

Tags: unity, launcher

I am running Ubuntu 14.10.  Suddenly, my launcher and top menu bar went missing.  I have rebooted but no success.  I have done a `unity --reset` without resolving anything.  The interesting thing is that I was using Chrome when I noticed it.  I have tried `ccsm`, reinstalled unity, but nothing worked.

I tried to log in as guest and everything seems fine in there.  The launcher is missing only from my account.  I cannot even start a terminal with `ctrl alt T`.  Can someone please help?

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of what your screen looks like and also, can you access TTY1? (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1`) Also, what GPU do you have? Is it a dedicated GPU or is it the AMD or Intel integrated graphics?

Comment: The screenshot just has all my document icons that I keep on desktop.  Nothing to the left (launcher), nothing on top.  I am running it on a laptop with integrated graphics.  Yes, I can see TTY1 and I was able to start an xterm by setting 'DISPLAY=:0'.  However, there is no toolbar on the xterm and so, I cannot move it or minimize it.

Comment: Okay. What GPU do you have?

Comment: There is no separate GPU.  And as I said, if I go in as Guest, everything seems to work fine.

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci -v` to your question (for the GPU stuff, though I think it is configuration and not a graphics issue). [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) question might help.

Comment: I had already gone over that question.  Did not help.  Anyway, I have solved the issue by deleting the configuration files.  Posting it separately as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In desperation, I deleted all of `.cache` and `.config` and logged in again.  Problem is solved.  I'll never know what caused it but at least, I know of a very bad way to fix it.

Comment: Yeah, this is a common bug, the solution you used is one of the ones [listed here](http://askubuntu.com/a/481620/136381). I had the exact same issue. Sorry I never got back to you, I got busy :(