# Computer logs out while I lock screen

Tags: 14.04, lightdm, lock-screen, logout

Recently, my laptop is behaving strangely sometimes. It doesn't usually does this but lately it frequently does.

The problem is that whenever I lock the screen, the computer logs out and closes all my applications. Is there any bug that cause this, or is it because I've  misconfigurated settings?

***EDIT***

**i have made a video from my mobile for this bug**  [lock error](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=leS05i3SclY)

**if it worked correctly while pressing lock** [lock working](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYIGs_c9b2Q)

Please, comment for additional information if needed. I don't know where to start looking.

Comment: Please check [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/481620/136173) link. Fix #5 did a trick for me.

Comment: the answer given by me didn't worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in Unity.  Please mark yourself as affected here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1451613

Answer (score 1):

Now i think there was problem in `compiz` after looking way around i found crash report of `compiz` in `/var/crash` just after crashing and the crash report was as in the screenshot

[image: crash report]

and i found that it wasn't send because there was

```
UnreportableReason:
 You have some obsolete package versions installed. Please upgrade the following packages and check if the problem still occurs:

 apt, apt-utils, compiz, compiz-core, compiz-gnome, compiz-plugins-default, libapt-inst1.5, libapt-pkg4.12, libcompizconfig0, libdecoration0
UpgradeStatus: No upgrade log present (probably fresh install)
_MarkForUpload: True
```

but update manager gui never showed updates for these packages and so i did

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

The following packages will be upgraded:
  apt apt-transport-https apt-utils compiz compiz-core compiz-gnome
  compiz-plugins compiz-plugins-default compiz-plugins-extra
  compiz-plugins-main compizconfig-settings-manager libapt-inst1.5
  libapt-pkg4.12 libcompizconfig0 libdecoration0 python-compizconfig
  python-pip python3-pip virtualbox virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-qt
21 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

and after this update hope this gets fixed.

Answer (score -1):

I'd liked to help ya, but I would also like to know a few things about your set up. Are you running Ubuntu solo, dual boot, or through VMWare of sometype (VirtualBox)?

I say this because it could be beyond the app software and the kernel depending on your model l-top and host OS.

Also with that update and upgrade, run a dist-upgrade to upgrade the kernel.

```
:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

This will upgrade the kernel, as well install the updates for the app software at that point in the kernels life span (upstream or whatever).

The screen shot below should take care of it!

By initiating the system settings followed by Brightness & Lock selection; and modifying the options to emulate the screenshot I have posted your problem should be solved.

SystemSettings>Brightness&Lock

If this doesn't work let me know!

[image: BrightnessLock]

P.S. Also if this doesnt work, run the who command from the command line and post your output.

```
:~$ who
```