# Background and pointer after ubuntu 14.04 login

Tags: 14.04, unity

I updated to 14.04 by reinstalling over the old 12.04 install.

After using the system for a few weeks I log in one day and there is no desktop / unity at all. Just a background and mouse pointer. The guest session logs in fine.

I've tried various posts ([Problems after upgrading to 14.04 (only background and pointer after login)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449845/problems-after-upgrading-to-14-04-only-background-and-pointer-after-login)) etc but it seems I'm shooting in the dark...

In the syslog there are errors about compiz.desktop killed by signal 9 and respawning too quickly but I can't see any fixes for my case.

I should add that a guest session logs in fine and the unity desktop displays as per normal...

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: Did you update or reinstall?

Comment: Long story...initially I updated from 12.04 to 14.04 but that completely broke the system. So I reinstalled via a USB stick. That worked okay as I just recreated the same user so didn't lose anything. That was 3-4 weeks before the blank screen problem I'm posting about here. Logged in one day and no desktop just a mouse pointer. The below commands have fixed it but of course the settings I had are gone. If it happens again I will try and trace it to a more specific folder.

Answer (score 1):

Something corrupted...

`sudo rm -rf ~/.config`

`sudo rm -rf ~/.cache`

...seems to sort it.