# ubuntu 14.04 lts not starting after logging in

Tags: boot, log

I installed ubuntu 14.04 lts by pendrive boot and it worked well also for last three week.

But from now I am seeing this weird thing.

I installed it on my windows 8.1 laptop.However,currently windows is working properly but when i enter correct password for log in and then press ENTER,the only thing can be seen is the Desktop background and mouse pointer.

somebody help me.I am in need of ubuntu very much.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything new that results to such behaviour?

Comment: please refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449845/problems-after-upgrading-to-14-04-only-background-and-pointer-after-login)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal - open with Ctrl+Alt+T and enter

```
export DISPLAY=:0   
sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

followed by `setsid unity`

Should work now :D