# I have a problem in login in after I upgrade my ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

My Ubuntu system was getting outdated, so I upgraded it to Ubuntu 14.04.4. Now after restarting I am not able to login. The only thing that I see is a black screen and asking me my username and password. After that I am not able to login in. I'm really confused.

Answer (score 0):

Have you been seeing incorrect password prompts? I assume this is a server install.

I am not even going to suggest checking your CAPS status. I am sure you did that.

Unless you provide more information in the question try the following post:

[Problems after upgrading to 14.04 (only background and pointer after login)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449845/problems-after-upgrading-to-14-04-only-background-and-pointer-after-login)