# No access to desktop in Unity for 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04, desktop-environments

I just updated to 16.04 from 14.04. Everything was fine. Just that there is nothing on desktop folder display in main screen. No icons, nothing. I cannot change wallpaper either. I have a few files in " Desktop " folder. None can be seen on Ubuntu's default Unity desktop.The system hangs once in a while as well. Could this be related ? Any solution ? Thanks.

[image: Not able to change wallpaper]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Comment: Not a duplicate. Everything loads, just no access to desktop

Comment: Could you add a screenshot? And have you tried the suggestions on the suggested duplicate?

Comment: @terdon , I have added screen shot. It is just that my problem is completely different. I simply could not access to desktop items and not able to change wallpaper.

Comment: Do you see a launcher and a dash? They seem to be missing from your screenshot. Or is that Gnome and not Unity?

Comment: Yes, I can. The screen shot shows Unity. 16.04 offer to take launcher to bottom. I have done that. Also resized icons.

Answer (score 1):

try and use "Ctrl + Alt + T" and this should load up the terminal. And follow Fix 5 to this referenced link below. I would do some more research on this issue as there may be more underlying issues with your upgrade.

The link below is in reference to the x session and nvidia drivers. potentially fix 5 is just refreshing unity for you so may resolve this issue.

good luck

[Problems after upgrading to 14.04 (only background and pointer after login)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449845/problems-after-upgrading-to-14-04-only-background-and-pointer-after-login/481620#481620)

Comment: Thank you @esefarm . I have Radeon graphics card. I used alternative drivers available in " Additional Drivers ".

Comment: Last resort would be to do just a fresh install of Ubuntu straight from 16.04. Have you got important data that needs to be backed up or is it backed up already? Not the best solution, good luck.

Comment: may be, I got lucky. The issue got sorted out by itself. I don't know how ? It just got ok by itself. Thank god.