# Why do I have two Alt+Tab application switchers?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, compiz, application-switcher

I have two Alt+Tab window switchers. It's super confusing to try to use them. This screenshot shows it pretty well:

[image]

How can I get back to the regular switcher (the one in the background)? I'm guessing the one in the front is the older switcher. It seems the current behavior is that both switchers are functioning, but the one on top get's the "last word." So the selected window in the bottom switcher will be second to the top, while the one in the top switcher will be in front.

Background:

I lost Unity and finally got it back, after trying a lot of things. What finally worked was solution #1 from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/481620/289003):

```
sudo rm -fr ~/.cache/compizconfig-1
sudo rm -fr ~/.compiz
```

Shortly before Unity disappeared (possibly the previous time the computer was on) I ran `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, which I am suspecting may have caused the problem.

What I've tried: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall compiz` and then log out.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Run `ccsm` from the terminal, or search the dash for Compiz and open `CompizConfig Settings Manager`. If it's not installed, run:

```
sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

In CCSM search for **Application Switcher** and uncheck the box beside it. The change should take effect immediately after you uncheck the box.

[image]

No idea what caused the problem in the first place.

Comment: Always Unity! GNOME sucks!